# Problema con clasificar datos en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

```
SELECT
libro.titulo AS "Titulo Libro",
sum(ventas.cantidad) AS "Cantidad_Comprada"
FROM libro 
left JOIN ventas ON
    libro.id = ventas.id_libro
GROUP BY libro.titulo
```

Quiero solo mostrar aquellos elementos que tienen una cantidad de `sum(ventas.cantidad)` mayor a 200, pero el comando `WHERE sum(ventas.cantidad)>200` no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ello debes utilizar [**HAVING**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
libro.titulo AS "Titulo Libro",
sum(ventas.cantidad) AS "Cantidad_Comprada"
FROM libro 
left JOIN ventas ON
    libro.id = ventas.id_libro
GROUP BY libro.titulo
HAVING sum(ventas.cantidad) > 200 -- Tu condición.
```

Comment: explica un poco mas el having por favor