# ¿Cómo usar HAVING y GROUP BY con funciones agregatorias en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¡Hola, compañeros! Estoy haciendo una aplicación en PHP y MySQL (por la parte del servidor) y me he encontrado con un problema. Actualmente tengo las siguientes tablas:

- Una con información de los alumnos
- Otra con los resultados que obtienen en algunas pruebas físicas (por ejemplo, la de 50 metros, el resultado de cada prueba se guarda en una columna diferente).
- Por último, una tabla para cada prueba que tiene la siguiente estructura: Nota mínima, Nota máxima, Sexo, Edad, Nota.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer la consulta SQL se muestren los resultados de las diferentes pruebas y luego las notas que obtengo de las tablas que he nombrado antes.

Para ello impongo las siguientes condiciones (las mismas para todas las pruebas que se realizan, simplemente cambiando el nombre):

- GREATEST(MIN(CASE WHEN Baremos[nombreprueba].Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento THEN Baremos[nombreprueba].MarcaMin END), Marcas.Marca[nombreprueba]) = Baremos[nombreprueba].MarcaMin

AND

- LEAST(MAX(CASE WHEN Baremos[nombreprueba].Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento AND Alumnos.Sexo = Baremos[nombreprueba].Sexo THEN Baremos[nombreprueba].MarcaMax END), Marcas.Marca[nombreprueba]) = Baremos[nombreprueba].MarcaMax

AND

- GREATEST(MIN(Baremos[nombreprueba].Edad), LEAST(MAX(Baremos[nombreprueba].Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca-Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = Baremos[nombreprueba].Edad

AND

- Alumnos.Sexo = Baremos[nombreprueba].Sexo

El problema es que, al tener funciones agregatorias, que son MAX() y MIN(), tengo que poner todas estas condiciones dentro de una cláusula HAVING en lugar de WHERE, y como nunca antes las había usado, me estoy liando un poco, porque simplemente con cambiar WHERE por HAVING no sirve, hay que utilizar algo llamado GROUP BY y no entiendo cómo hay que usarlo.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Qué campos hay que incluir en el GROUP BY? ¿Para qué sirve? ¿Debo mantener las condiciones que no tengan funciones agregatorias en WHERE y pasar el resto al HAVING?

Agradecería mucho una ayudita, estoy atascado y tengo la aplicación casi terminada. ¡Muchas gracias!

P.D.: os dejo aquí el código SQL completo para que podáis verlo. ¡Gracias!

```sql
SELECT
   Alumnos.IdAlumno AS idalumno,
   Alumnos.Nombre AS nombre,
   Alumnos.Apellido1 AS apellido1,
   Alumnos.Apellido2 AS apellido2,
   Alumnos.Sexo AS sexo,
   Alumnos.AnoNacimiento AS anonacimiento,
   Marcas.AnoMarca AS anomarca,
   Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento AS edad,
   Marcas.CursoMarca AS cursomarca,
   Marcas.Peso AS peso,
   Marcas.Envergadura AS envergadura,
   Marcas.Estatura AS estatura,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1,
   IFNULL(BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1,
   IFNULL(BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1,
   IFNULL(BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremos50metros_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremos50metros_1,
   IFNULL(Baremos50metros_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremos50metros_1,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebade10x5_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremosPruebade10x5_1,
   IFNULL(BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremosPruebade10x5_1,
   IFNULL(Marcas.MarcaBaremosTestdeCooper_1, '---') AS MarcaBaremosTestdeCooper_1,
   IFNULL(BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Nota, '---') AS NotaBaremosTestdeCooper_1,
   Marcas.Comentarios AS Comentarios 
FROM
   Alumnos,
   Marcas,
   BaremosSaltohorizontal_1,
   BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1,
   BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1,
   Baremos50metros_1,
   BaremosPruebade10x5_1,
   BaremosTestdeCooper_1 
GROUP BY
   Alumnos.AnoNacimiento,
   Marcas.AnoMarca,
   Marcas.IdAlumno,
   BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad,
   BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMin,
   BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1,
   BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad,
   BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMin,
   BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1,
   BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad,
   BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMin,
   BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1,
   Baremos50metros_1.Edad,
   Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMin,
   Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremos50metros_1,
   BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad,
   BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMin,
   BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebade10x5_1,
   BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad,
   BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMin,
   BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMax,
   Marcas.MarcaBaremosTestdeCooper_1 
HAVING
   Alumnos.IdAlumno = Marcas.IdAlumno 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1) = BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosSaltohorizontal_1) = BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.Sexo 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1) = BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1) = BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosLanzamientodebalónmedicinal_1.Sexo 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1) = BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1) = BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosPruebadeFlexibilidad_1.Sexo 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         Baremos50metros_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremos50metros_1) = Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         Baremos50metros_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = Baremos50metros_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremos50metros_1) = Baremos50metros_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(Baremos50metros_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(Baremos50metros_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = Baremos50metros_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = Baremos50metros_1.Sexo 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebade10x5_1) = BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosPruebade10x5_1) = BaremosPruebade10x5_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosPruebade10x5_1.Sexo 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
      THEN
         BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMin 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosTestdeCooper_1) = BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMin 
   AND LEAST(MAX(
   CASE
      WHEN
         BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad = Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento 
         AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Sexo 
      THEN
         BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMax 
   END
), Marcas.MarcaBaremosTestdeCooper_1) = BaremosTestdeCooper_1.MarcaMax 
   AND GREATEST(MIN(BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad), LEAST(MAX(BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad), Marcas.AnoMarca - Alumnos.AnoNacimiento)) = BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Edad 
   AND Alumnos.Sexo = BaremosTestdeCooper_1.Sexo
```

Comment: trata de colocar solo la pregunta y el problema puntual para que te podamos ayudar; la verdad se me es dificil entender la pregunta con lo que dices ; podria darte un ejemplo de como se usa el having con el group by pero no se si es lo que quieres

Comment: @JackNavaRow te agradecería que me dieras un ejemplo de cómo usarlos, no me aclaro mucho. Tienes razón, no me he explicado muy bien. El problema que tengo es que tengo el código largo que he puesto al final y al ejecutarlo me dice #1054 - Unknown column 'BaremosSaltohorizontal_1.MarcaMin' in 'having clause', cuando la columna sí que existe. ¡Gracias!

Comment: una respuesta de como usar el having https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/106908/28035 , observa que el agrupo primero(bien sea usando un sum un distinct y luego con el having filtro la info, tambien pudo haber colocado el alias y no iba a tener problemas

Comment: @JackNavaRow Vale, ya lo entiendo mejor, muchas gracias. Pero todavía no me ha quedado claro qué campos hay que incluir en el GROUP BY, ¿podrías aclarármelo? ¡Gracias!